# builtins.UnboundLocalError: local variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have not been able to find a solution for this exact issue that I am having so im hoping someone can shed some light on this.

I have this code here:

```
def numberOfPorts():
    try:
        ports = int(input("How many ports do you want to configure? "))
    except:
        print("You did not specify a number.")
        numberOfPorts()
    return ports
```

Now if i run this code and input a number, the function runs fine.

```
numberOfPorts()
How many ports do you want to configure? 10
10
```

But when I run this function a second time and i specify a string, the except code is triggered and my print statement executes and the input function asks for input again.  This is what I want.  I then give the script a number but I then get the following error:

```
numberOfPorts()
How many ports do you want to configure? foobar
You did not specify a number.
How many ports do you want to configure? 10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Python Shell, prompt 53, line 1
  Python Shell, prompt 49, line 8
builtins.UnboundLocalError: local variable 'ports' referenced before assignment
```

im sure this is really simple I just need a bit of insight on what is the root cause.

Comment: on exception, the `try` never completes so `port` is never set. Then when you do get a valid value, it exists within the context of your recursive function call, which is a different scope

Comment: Use a `while` loop, don't use recursion for this.

Comment: @avigil Ok, that makes sense.  So as "abccd" mentioned is it recommended to use a while loop in this context?

Comment: @JoelDeLaTorre in Python, you almost always want to prefer some looping control structure over recursion. There are some algorithms which are more naturally expressed in a recursive form, and in that case, go ahead, but just use a while-loop here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this -

```
def numberOfPorts():
    try:
        ports = int(input("How many ports do you want to configure? "))
        return ports
    except:
        print("You did not specify a number.")
        return numberOfPorts()
```

But recursion is an overkill for this problem. Why? Because we will just be filling our memory stack with our function calls till we get an integer. So `while` loop should suffice -

```
def numberOfPorts():
    ports = None
    while ports is None:
        try:
            ports = int(raw_input("How many ports do you want to configure? "))
        except ValueError:
            print("You did not specify a number.")
    return ports
```

Comment: I would use `None` here instead of `0`, if only because `0` might be a reasonable user input.

Comment: One more thing, use `while ports is None:`

Comment: `None` is `falsy` in python so `not None` is `truthy`

Comment: Yes, but then it will *accept any falsy value including `0`* which is what we are trying to avoid.

Comment: the `pass` in the `except` block is unnecessary